# How to create shape file of a district using ArcGIS

Tags: gis, arcgis

I wanted to create shape files of my district in ArcMap. I assume it's possible by drawing lines over img of my district. Can anyone give links or sources to create shape files. Suppose I wanted to create shape files of Mangaluru corporation of India for a study purpose. And use in geoserver.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make an attempt at creating shapes first and share the code you have tried if you need help.

Comment: But i dont know where to start. can you please give me a starting point.

Comment: @Étienne Laneville

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only point you to the official documentation

1. [Creating a new shapefile](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/creating-a-new-shapefile.htm)
2. [A quick tour of editing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing/a-quick-tour-of-editing.htm)
3. [Exporting features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/exporting-features.htm)